# How can I get a perl script to execute a command from a text file?

Tags: perl, printing

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fileName = "fileName.txt";

if (-e $fileName) {
        my $read = open($fileName);
        print "File exists and has been read\n";
        eval $read;
        unlink $fileName;
}
else {
        print "File does not yet exist\n";
}
```

This is what I have so far. The goal of this script is to check for the existence of a file, and then execute the commands in the file if the file is present, but any time I attempt to run this script I get an error saying that I cannot use the string "fileName.txt" as a symbol ref, but even when I hard code in the file name instead of setting it as a variable, I get an error stating that $fileName requires an explicit package name.

Comment: Be very wary doing this - there's all sorts of nasty things that can occur as the result of `eval` of a userspace string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling open incorrectly.

Also, once you have opened the file, you need to read the lines inside it.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $fileName = "fileName.txt";

if (-e $fileName) {
        open my $read, '<', $fileName;
        local $/; # slurp mode;
        my $data = <$read>;
        close $read;
        print "File exists and has been read\n";
        eval $data;
        unlink $fileName;
}
else {
        print "File does not yet exist\n";
}
```

Comment: You're clobbering `$/` globally when you should be localizing it instead, e.g. `my $data = do { local $/; <$read> };`. You should also check the return value of `open` or `use autodie`.

Answer (score 5):

#### Slurp the File then [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)

You're not using [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) properly.  Open is intended to create a file handle but you still need to read from the file handle to load the contents.

The following slurps the file like modeled in [perlfaq5 - How can I read in an entire file all at once?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-read-in-an-entire-file-all-at-once%3f)

```
my $code = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $fileName or die $!;  
    local $/;
    <$fh> 
};
```

Alternatively, you can use a module like [`File::Slurp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp):

```
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);

my $code = read_file($fileName);
```

Then you can just `eval` the loaded code like you were originally doing:

```
eval $code;
```

#### Execute external Perl code using [`do EXPR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html)

On the other hand, you can execute external perl code without needing to load the file's contents by using [`do EXPR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html).  You can view the documentation by using [`perldoc -f do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html):

> - `do EXPR`
>
>   Uses the value of EXPR as a filename and executes the contents of the file as a Perl script.
>
>   ```
>       1.      do 'stat.pl';
>   ```
>
>   is largely like
>
>   ```
>       1.      eval `cat stat.pl`;
>   ```
>
>   except that it's more concise, runs no external processes, keeps track of the current filename for error messages, searches the `@INC` directories, and updates `%INC` if the file is found. See [`@INC` in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40INC) and [`%INC` in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%25INC) for these variables. It also differs in that code evaluated with [`do` FILENAME](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) cannot see lexicals in the enclosing scope; [`eval` STRING](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) does. It's the same, however, in that it does reparse the file every time you call it, so you probably don't want to do this inside a loop.
>
>   [read more ...](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html)

which would let you just write `do $fileName`.

(Note that `do EXPR` is **not** the same as the `do BLOCK` used in the first code example.)

`do EXPR` has weaknesses however; it will compile and execute the same file more than one time if you tell it to. It's okay for quick and dirty scripting, but the safer and more powerful mechanism Perl provides is [modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules), which are loaded using [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) and [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) (note how `require` is like a more robust version of `do FILE`, and `use` is like a wrapper around `require` that also imports things from the module).

Comment: @Miller I avoided using `do BLOCK` to avoid potential confusion with the `do EXPR` explanation that followed. I'll keep your edit and add a note to the same effect, though.

Comment: Added mild perfectionist level of documentation to cover your potential confusion concern.